# Parallel Script Transformation Using Same Row.Names - the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, ssis

I have setup two identical data flows, each containing
OLE DB Source->Script Transformation->OLE DB Command

The script transformation takes some of the Row data and uses it to get a Byte[] stream from ReportExecutionService, and writes it to a PDF.  It works fine when executing a single data flow.  When I try to run two in parallel, I get the following error:

The process cannot access the file 'xxx' because it is being used by another process.

Here is how I am writing the files.

```
writeToFilePath = Variables.FilePathPrefix + @"\" + Row.PathToDocumentData;
FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(writeToFilePath);
stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length);
stream.Close();
```

In reality, Row.PathToDocumentData is unique.  When it runs two in parallel, it seems as if there is a scope issue with Row.PathToDocumentData not having separate instances.

How can I run these two data flows in parallel?

Comment: Are the two tasks writing to different files? I would maybe try using `Dts.Events.FireInformation` to debug this, e.g., print the name of the file you're trying to access and the task that is trying to access it.

Comment: I will give that a shot.  The files are unique.  Each script writes different files.